# ヨーダスタイルについて

Tags: c, coding-style

とある回答への某コメントで

> I was tempted to give you an upvote until I saw "Yoda style". That style was horrible even when it was useful. Nowadays, every decent compiler will generate a warning about assignments where conditionals are expected, so that style is still horrible and now completely useless.

とされていて、(拙訳、重大な間違いがあったら修正下さい)
「ヨーダスタイルを見るまではアップボート(良回答投票)しようと思ってた。
それはかつては役に立ちましたが寒気のするものでした。
今ではコンパイラがそのような条件を代入とすることについて警告を発するので
まるで役に立たないばかりかまだ寒気のするスタイルです。」

えらく嫌われるもんだなと思います。
（この方だけでなく他にも（既に場所は忘れましたが）似たようなコメントを見たことがあります）
私は以前の大流行も知っていますし、現在ではほとんど使われなくなったと感じていますが、
実際の所
`1==value`と書いても`value==1`と書いてもプログラムとしての意味は変わりませんし、
実際`1=value`になっていたら警告がでるでしょうし、
clang では`value=1`で警告がでますが、
gcc ではオプションを付けなければ警告はでません。（新しいバージョンだと違う？）

私的にはどっちでもそんなに目くじら立てるようなこと(また回答としての評価を下げること)なのかな？と思います。

また関数の返値の場合も（次の例の場合代入でさえないがヨーダスタイルと言われる(?)）
`1==func()`よりも`func()==1`の方が好まれるような感じを受けます。

これ（ヨーダスタイル）って英語の文脈的に生理的に受け付けないとかそういう意味があるんでしょうか？
なぜそこまで毛嫌いされるのですか？

Comment: なぜ毛嫌いされるのか、と言う主観を主題にした質問はこのサイトにはそぐわないように思います。なぜ現在ではそのような書き方をする必要はないと言えるのかなら、そんな質問はありだと思いますが、質問者さんは後者の答えはご存知のように見えます。

Comment: @OOPer   そうですね。個人的な主観の問題なのかもしれません。英語圏の慣習についてほとんど知らないので、英語圏の人にとって（メリットがないならば）許容できない書き方なのかと疑問に思った次第です。 そのような自然言語的要因がない（個人の主観である）のであればこの質問は削除しようかと思います。

Comment: また、コーディングスタイルに関しての質問自体は（これも主観になりがちではありますけど、良いスタイル、悪いスタイルというのは）ありだと思っています。言い換えれば、この質問では、「受け容れ難いスタイル」だと思っている人が少なからずいて、それはなぜなのかということで、「悪いスタイル」とするにはそれなりの理由があるのだろうと思います。

Comment: 蛇足ですが、「なぜ現在ではそのような書き方を‌​する必要はないか？」 という質問ではありません。別に必要無くてもこのように書いて悪くは無いでしょう、何が悪い（評価を下げる）の？ということです。

Comment: 主観的でよければ「何が悪いのか」はいくらでも書けるんですが、最初のコメントと矛盾する行為は慎んでおきます。当のコメントを「毛嫌いしている」と評するのはそれほど的外れではないとは思いますが、主観的な感想の根拠を求めるのなら、そのコメントを残された本人に聞いてみるのが筋ではないでしょうか。

Comment: @OOPer  当の御本人は現在既にコメントを削除してしまっています。削除されたコメントについて相手を探して問うのは筋ではないと思います。（削除理由はおそらく回答者からのコメントがあったためだと思います）「主観的でよければ「何が悪いのか」はいくらでも書ける」 のであれば、私的にはもやもやするので、主観的でもいいのでたくさんの理由を教えて下さい。

Comment: 主観的な議論自体が問題だと思っている人間に「私的にはもやもやする」という理由で問題行為を促すというのもなかなかの行為ですね。Wikipedia等お調べください。

Comment: えっと「いくらでも書ける」んですよね？ こういう場合「当人に聞いてみるのが筋」らしいのですが・・・

Comment: 大前提を読み落とさないでください。「主観的でよければ」です。こちらで主観的な議論をするべきではありませんので、大前提がなりたっておりません。

Comment: あちらでも主観的な議論をするべきではないですよね？

Comment: あちらというのがどちらなのか全く明記されていませんが、本家stackoverflowならその通りですね。

Comment: 実りのないコメントという点で、こういうのは意味がないというのは合意します。

Comment: この投稿から派生した議論を他サイトで見かけたので貼っておきます https://teratail.com/questions/64207 嫌われる理由、使わない理由ではなく、今でも使うべき場面・理由があるのか、という点にフォーカスしているようです。

Comment: @unarist  ありがとうございます。teratailは基本見てないので、こういう興味深い内容が見ることができて（私的にも）よかったです。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

コメントで色々会話されているようですが，ヨーダスタイルがなぜ現代では用いられていないのかについてここで回答として書いておくことは，後で読む人のために有用だと思うので書かせてください．

そもそもヨーダスタイルとはif文などの条件判断部内の式で

```
value==1
```

と書かずに

```
1==value
```

と定数を左辺に，変数を右辺に書くスタイルを指します．
ヨーダスタイルという名称は，スターウォーズに出てくるヨーダという長老ポジションのキャラクターが倒置法を多用して喋ることに由来しています．

なぜこのように逆にするかというと，`==`演算子を打ち間違って`=`演算子にした場合に結果が異なるためです．
前者では

```
value=1
```

となり，C言語においては，式の結果は（`value`の元の値に関わらず）代入後の`value`の値，すなわち`1`となります．ここで，C言語においては代入文がif文の条件判断部に書いてあった場合もシンタックスエラーではないというのがミソで，原因が分かりにくいバグの原因になります．

一方，後者では

```
1=value
```

となり，定数に代入しようとしているためこれは明確にシンタックスエラーとなります．

こうした人間のケアレスミスによるバグを無くすために過去には使われることがあったヨーダスタイルですが，現代では使うことは誤りだと考えられています．

その理由としては，「ソースコードはコンピュータではなく人間のために読みやすくあるべき」という前提があることが挙げられます．

ヨーダスタイルは，一言で言ってしまえば，コンパイラが人間のケアレスミスを発見しやすくするためのスタイルです．すなわちコンピュータのための記法です．

一方で，英語がどうということは一旦置いておいても，少なくともC言語においては変数は左辺に，定数は右辺に書くことが自然です（代入演算子との一貫性がある）．なので，ヨーダスタイルを知らないプログラマが既に書かれたヨーダスタイルのコードを読んだ時，少なからず面食らうことは容易に想像できます．

これらは「ソースコードはコンピュータではなく人間のために読みやすくあるべき」という前提に反します．

また，質問者の方がおっしゃるように現代のコンパイラはこの手の比較演算子と代入演算子の書き間違えは普通に検出することができます．

ちなみにGCCでは`-Wparentheses`オプションを付ければ警告が出るようになります．（今回の話とは関係ありませんが，コンパイラの警告機能はデフォルトで全て有効にしておくべきです．GCCでは`-Wall`オプションで全ての警告機能を有効にできます）

以上のことから，最早現代においてはヨーダスタイルを使用する必要はまったく無くなりました．
新しいコードを書く上でヨーダスタイルを使うのは止めましょう．
巨人の肩に乗るべきです．ヨーダは小柄すぎます．

Comment: 「誤り」は言いすぎ（「よろしくない」ぐらいがいいかと）にしても、納得のいく理由ですね。「GCCでは警告が出ないという話」 は、「gcc ではオプションを付けなければ警告はでません。」なのでニュアンスが違うかと思います。

Comment: GCCのオプションについてはそうですね．書き方が正しくなかったです．修正します．